# why is the run button grayed out in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just imported a project from github, and after trying to run the project, I realized the `run` button was grayed out. In other words, I can't run the project. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Open you project by selecting `buil.gradle` from android studio. which sync you project  and enable project for run.

Comment: Did your problem resolved?

Answer (score 17):

There can be many reason for grayed out `run` button.
Let's check one by one:

> Configure the application.

Click the edit configuration in the combo box left to run button then select your app module:
[image]

if the configuration is ok,then:

> Check the `AndroidMainfest.xml` file and fix all error.

if this is also ok then

> Just close the project `File > Close Project` and then reopen it,sometimes it works for me.

Comment: Thanks... I added a new Configuration and named it App. The run button became available; however, when I click run another "edit configuration" box open. telling me "no module available"... when I click the module drop down menu, nothing is available to select.

Comment: I imported this project from github. I was working on a different computer (Linux) when I opened in Android Studio (windows) this happened. I wonder if there's an incompatibility on sdk versions?

Comment: ok, my AndroidManifest.xml file seems to have a few errors. http://pctechtips.org/pics/Capture.PNG

Comment: @miatech Where is your mainfest closing tag? Your mainfest should be closed like this <mainfest> ....all of your application and activity and everything goes here..... </mainfest> i think that is the error

Comment: @miatech that was the problem in your mainfest right?

Answer (score 3):

I had my app folder in a parent folder and had opened the parent folder as if it was a project, so Android Studio was just acting like a file explorer with the build and debug buttons grayed out. I opened the actual project folder and everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:-

Go To Project `Structure>Project>NOSDK`

Change `NOSDK` to the latest `ANDROID API PLATFORM`

Then go to `MODULE` and DO THE SAME

Answer (score 0):

Option to try

1. Check module selected correctly In Edit Configuration, Check if any error there at bottom
2. File -> Sync Project with gradle file
3. File -> Invalidate cache and restart
4. Still Not work then final option which work in my case is to remove .gradle  ,   .idea  folder then reopen project again (this folder re-generate again)